# Why doesn't the same display in emulator and phone

Tags: java, android, date

```
String[] datesReason = {
            "New Years Day",
            "Martin Luther King, Jr.'s Birthday",
            "Asian Lunar New Year"
};
public String[] suspendedDates = {
            "Friday, January 1",
            "Monday, January 18",
            "Saturday, March 5"
};

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE, LLLL d", Locale.US);

Spannable WordToSpan = new SpannableString("Today is: ");
WordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.dateholiday), 0, WordToSpan.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tvTD.setText(WordToSpan);

Spannable WordToSpan1 = new SpannableString("" + df.format(new Date()) + "");
WordToSpan1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#4787ED")), 0, WordToSpan1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tvTD.append(WordToSpan1);
```

The above code displays `Today is: Saturday, March 5` when I debug from my PC to an Android emulator. When I debug with a Android device (running Lollipop, Jellybean, etc.), It shows `Today is: S, March 5`

I am also using the above to compare to day's date to do other functions, and I have the following, which compares the date to today:

```
SetRows myImage = data.get(position); //SetRows is what I am using to populate a ListView with texts/images
int inReason = myImage.name.indexOf(",");
String strR = myImage.name.substring(0, inReason);
Spannable WordToSpan = new SpannableString(strR); //e.g. strR = "Saturday"
WordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#4787ED")), 0, WordToSpan.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
String strRNext = myImage.name.substring(inReason, myImage.name.length());
Spannable WordToSpan1 = new SpannableString(strRNext); //e.g. strRNext = "March 5"
WordToSpan1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.dateholiday), 0, WordToSpan1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

if (myImage.name.contains(df.format(Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US).getTime()))) { //if Today is Saturday, March 5, the set the background of the list item...
   Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(myImage.name.contains(df.format(Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US).getTime()))), 2000).show();
   row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F0DEEDF3"));
}
else { //otherwise use the default background...
   row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCF5F5F5"));
}
```

In the emulator the correct list item will get the background but in the phone, it doesn't because it displays `S` instead of `Saturday`

Any idea why that is happening and how can I resolve it.

Comment: "Five-count patterns (such as "MMMMM") used for the shortest non-numeric representation of a field were introduced in Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean MR2, API level 18)" (from [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)). If your `minSdkVersion` is less than 18, you will need to work out some other solution anyway.

Comment: I currently have `11` as the minSDK version. Is that why the date is coming up as `S` instead of `Satuday` in my Lollipop phone? The emulator is running 4.1.2, maybe that is why it's working in the emulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> E  day of week (Text)  E/EE/EEE:Tue, EEEE:Tuesday, EEEEE:T

You are using "EEEEE" which will display just the first letter, so you need to remove one 'E' if you want to show the full day.

Comment: Damn it ;), you beat me to it. I was looking at it and finally figure it out. I will test it out and let you know if it worked. Thanks.